# How To Open link when mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make the link `<a href="www.site.com">Click here</a>` open the link when the mouse is hovered over "Click here"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML one line solution:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onmouseover="click();">Click here</a>
```

We are using inline events with Javascript, triggering the click event to the current link element, when mouse hovering.

To learn more: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can give that element a name like name='blah'. Then access it using javascript andtake advantage of the javascript MouseOver event. For more information on that just google it, it's everywhere.